# Use previous result only inside group regex

Tags: regex, string, perl, pattern-matching

I am trying to find all words that has multiple letter, but I have one problem. I need to return whole word, not letters.
I have tried to do this way

```
(?:(\w)(?=\1{1}))
```

But this expression also returns letters, but I need to get whole matched word.
Is it possible to make such expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/(\b\w*(\w)(?=\2)\w*\b)/
```

And whole words will be available in captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB2jK2/1)